# Create and use tokens in texarea to add templates

Tags: php, variables, templates

I am working on a project where I need to add a email template that uses variables for name, address and phone number.
In my database i have 2 tables

1. Users - with name, address, phone number and category
2. Email_templates - for different email templates like Christmas, New year etc

on front end i have a textarea to add templates in database.

My template contains tokens like {name}, {address}, {phone} that are replaced with respective user detail when I send emails using that template.

Now i am able to fetch all details for users and email templates but not able to replace the tokens with values with php.
i tried str_replace to replace {name} and other tokens with variables like $user->name.

Comment: What if you define the tokens with the variable then unset it

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to replace tokens :

```
$template_body = file_get_contents('Email template file path');

$email_values= array(
'name'=>$user->name,
'address'=>$user->address,
'phone'=>$user->phone,           
);
if(count($email_values)>0)
{
   foreach($email_values as $key=>$value)
   {    
      $template_body = str_replace('{'.$key.'}',$value,$template_body);
   }
}

return $template_body;
```

Comment: your method helps me to write code in proper manner, i am already using str_replace.